# Why Tensorflow multi-GPU training so slow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Recently I modified my model to train on 2-GPUs on the same machine. But the speed was same as that of one GPU.

The question is:

1.Why backward covers so long time range? Is this the normal case?

2.It seems that there was no performance bottleneck in forward, but why the brown region in the image is so sparse, but the gray region above showed that there was indeed computation on GPU?

3.There are a lot peer-to-peer memcpy after forward, why? What's the operation?BTW, there are not much BN in my model.

[image: timeline after warm-up (all other computation not marked is either forward or backward)]

Comment: This cannot be answered without seeing the code for averaging gradients. You can fetch the gradients using TF and then do averaging (This can cause some memcpys) . You can use NCCL, ... This all depends on *your* actual implementations. Other open questions are DMA available or not?

Comment: Thank you. I used replica_model_fn in Tensorflow1.6 with estimator, all of gradient reduce is automatic.